# Debian : Setting path for Node with root accessible globally

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell, bashrc

I have downloaded `NodeJS` setup and have it inside at `/home/deploy/nodejs`. I am trying to set its path, but it's not working out. I am logged in as root, and I would like to access `nodejs` and `npm` accessible as root as well. For that I tried adding in `/root/.bashrc` the following content :

```
PATH=/usr/bin/node:/home/deploy/nodejs/bin/
PATH=/usr/bin/npm:/home/deploy/nodejs/bin/
```

After that I tried `node` and `npm`, but none of them worked. What am I doing wrong?

The files in `/home/deploy/nodejs/bin` are node, node_modules and npm. I tried the .deb installer, but that is not installing npm, only nodejs, so I have to do all this... :-(

*Update*

```
npm
/home/deploy/nodejs/bin/npm: 1: /home/deploy/nodejs/bin/npm: dirname: not found
/home/deploy/nodejs/bin/npm: 2: exec: /node: not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You're overwriting the path which breaks a lot of your system. The correct line would be:

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/deploy/nodejs/bin"
```

With that, you're appending something to PATH, instead of overriding it. Also, the PATH consists of directories (and not files), and `/usr/bin` should be already in it, rendering the first part useless.

2) "Did you try turning it off and on again?" - the `.bashrc` is only loaded on login, or when using `source ~/.bashrc`. If you want to change the path system-wide, you should do so in `/etc/profile`.

3) Also, make sure that there is a `/home/deploy/nodejs/bin/node` file, and that it's executable (should definitely be the case if you installed it correctly, but you can run `chmod a+x /home/deploy/nodejs/bin/node /home/deploy/nodejs/bin/npm` to be extra-sure)

Comment: Okay..When I gave source ~/.bashrc, then other commands like ls, nano, etc have stopped working in that terminal, but when I opened a new ssh connection, then it worked. But npm command is still not working. I am adding error log for npm in main post.

Comment: Oh, I just see that you're actually overwriting the path and therefore all information about where ls, nano and so on are located! I updated my answer :D

Comment: Your command in 1st worked. Thank you very much. :-) Can you also tell me how I can add it in /etc/profile, just for information. Thank you. :-)

Comment: The `/etc/profile` is pretty much the same as the `~/.bashrc`, just for all users. This means, you can just add the same line at the very bottom of this file.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was the following:

1. download the correct version (in my case for ARMv7 for Raspberry Pi 3b) from [NodeJS site](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. unpack in /opt/node (using `xz -d` and `tar xf` )
3. this usually leaves you with everything in a sub directory, so I moved everything : `mv node-v14.15.4-linux-armv7l/* .`
4. make soft links to the /usr/bin for node, npm and npx

```bsh
    root@fileserver:/opt/node# ln -s /opt/node/bin/npx /usr/bin/npx
    root@fileserver:/opt/node# ln -s /opt/node/bin/node /usr/bin/node
    root@fileserver:/opt/node# ln -s /opt/node/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

then everything works like a charm. notice you might have to alter the rights using chmod to allow access by other users.

For a user based solution have a look at https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation#how-to-install-nodejs-via-binary-archive-on-linux